# need to add 2 textbox so that user can type in and add to arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button, textbox

ok so i have 2 arrays  and i have to add a gui in html javascript that will allow a user to type in a new country and population and have a button that will add the new elements in to the arrays. how can i do that?

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var countries = new Array();
    countries[0] = "Nigeria";
    countries[1] = "Irag";
    countries[2] = "Philippines";
    countries[3] = "Indonesia";
    countries[4] = "Egypt";
    countries[5] = "Russia";
    countries[6] = "Vietnam";
    countries[7] = "Ethiopia";
    countries[8] = "Mexico";

    var population = new Array();
    population[0] = "166,629,000";
    population[1] = "33,330,000";
    population[2] = "92,337,000";
    population[3] = "237,641,000";
    population[4] = "82,940,000";
    population[5] = "143,300,000";
    population[6] = "87,840,000";
    population[7] = "84,320,000";
    population[8] = "112,336,000";

</script>
```

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
//Easier way to define and populate an array
var countries =
[
    "Nigeria",
    "Iraq",
    "Philippines",
    //And so on
];

//Same for population

//Function to add the new data
function addData()
{
    //push() adds an element at the end of an array
    countries.push(document.getElementById("myCountry").value);
    population.push(document.getElementById("myPopulation").value);
}

//Add the click event
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = addData;
```